# Succinct notation for the set of all initial segments of $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: terminology, natural-numbers

The $j^{th}$ initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $\{i:i\leq j\}$ is typically denoted by $\mathbb{N}_{\leq j}$. One can easily denote the set of all such segments by $\{\mathbb{N}_{\leq j}, j\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Is there a succincter "standard" way, something like $\mathbb{N}_{\leq\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: I would suggest making something up, it's not a set which gets "notated" a lot. But I'd go for something typographically simpler along the lines of $I_j = [1,...,j]$ and $\mathbb{I} = \{I_j \mid j \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Although I don't like how the "blackboard bold capital I" character $\mathbb{I}$ came out...

Comment: That's the notation in https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Initial_Segment_of_Natural_Numbers

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard notation for this.

In the [von Neumann construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Von_Neumann_construction) of natural numbers, $n$ *is* the set $\{0,1,\dots, n-1\}$. This is clever and elegant but likely to be confusing for readers, unless your topic is exactly the set-theoretical construction of numbers.

Better be clear than use non-standard notation, however clever.

Comment: On this site I have seen $[[j]]$ for $  \Bbb N_{\leq j}.  $ But It's not a common notation.